# Datastore in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do i store data which is more than 10 MB in google app engine?
put() from datastore allows only 1 MB.
do I need to slice my data into chunks of 1MB each and store ? 
or is there any other way ?

Comment: For Media rich sites, Google App Engine is not really cost competitive.  You should consider switching to a different cloud if you need lots of storage or transfer.  Amazon EC2 is pretty good in that range.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason that an application can't use AppEngine _and_ Amazon S3 to build an application. What could be more in the spirit of 'the cloud' than building an application that uses multiple providers?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy What are you basing that assessment on? App Engine's storage and transfer prices are in line with other cloud providers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the datastore, yes, you'll need to use smaller chunks.  You could also use the [Blobstore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/).